# iPhone is there a faster way to secure the app than a pin screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, password-protection

I'm currently using a pin view in one of my app and am running into an issue where the user has to first unlock phone, then navigate to the app and then unlock the app with a pin code. I know it works, but I would like the security (let the user in/lock out of the app) to be resolved faster.

I know that android uses a swipe gesture across dots, which seems to work faster than iPhone's pin screen.

My question is: **what (faster) alternatives to the in-app pin screen are there to secure an iPhone app?**

Comment: What if it cached the result so they didn't have to enter a pin quite so often? (every hour, day etc)

Comment: Anything you can image and implement?

Comment: If you like the android style unlocking, you could probably implement that yourself.

Comment: Found this one: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/splockscreen

Comment: Another lock screen: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kkgesturelockview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the android style lock, you could look at this code and modify it for your needs: https://github.com/GrioSF/Android-Pattern-Lock-on-iOS